# Internet Explorer does not prompt for Client Certificate

Tags: internet-explorer, iis, ssl

I have an ASP.Net WebApi REST service deployed in IIS7.5. I'm testing to see how to add a Client Certificate authentication process to this service so that only specific clients will be able to access the service.

**Current Situation:**

- I created a root certificate, a server certificate and a client
  certificate using xca. The server certificate and client certificate
  are signed using the created root certificate.
- I used mmc to import the created root certificate to Local
  Computer\Trusted Root Certification Authorities on both server and
  client.
- I used mmc to import the created server certificate to Local
  Computer\Personal on the server.
- I used mmc to import the created client certificate to Current
  User\Personal on the client.
- In IIS, I created HTTPS binding pointing to the created server
  certificate. I also configured 'Require SSL' and 'Require Client
  Certificate' for the service in question.
- I configured the REST service to include CORS headers in response.
  This is for supporting request of cross-domain resources.

**The Problem:**

When I try to access the service on the client using Resttesttest (http://resttesttest.com/) in Internet Explorer, I do not get prompted to select a Client Certificate and the service does not return any data. The error code in IIS log is 500. **However**, doing the same test in Chrome allows me to select a Client Certificate and the service returns valid data. Testing using fiddler also allows me to access the service properly.

**Performed Troubleshooting Steps:**

- I checked Certificates in Internet Explorer - the created root
  certificate shows under Trusted Root Certification Authorities and
  the created client certificate shows under Personal.
- I checked the client certificate's certification path - both the root
  certificate and the client certificate shows ok.
- I understand that Internet Explorer by default does not prompt for
  Client Certificates if there's only one available. I added my server
  to Trusted Site and then set custom level - Don't prompt for client
  certificate selection when only one client certificate exists to
  Disabled. Tested again - still I don't get prompt to select
  certificate.
- Used wireshark to capture the traffic during the initial handshake -
  I can see that server sent 'Certificate Request' to the client.
  Furthermore, I see the root certificate I created in the list of
  accepted root certificates. Right after getting the Certificate
  Request, the client sends ACK then FIN, ACK. The server responds with
  RST, ACK and the communication ends.
- Upgrade Internet Explorer 10 to Internet Explorer 11 - no difference.
- I found a stackoverflow question that's very similar to the problem I
  have:

  [Browser is not prompting for a client certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014288/browser-is-not-prompting-for-a-client-certificate)

  But in that case it seems that Chrome doesn't work either. For my
  case Chrome and Fiddler work, only Internet Explorer doesn't. This is
  what confuses me the most.

I'm quite out of idea of what I might have missed, so any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Many thanks,

David

Comment: Did you include `Digital Signature` in the Key Usages extension, and `Client Authentication` in the Enhanced Key Usage extension.  I think IE uses the latter to determine whether it is valid for showing in the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might the fix for you.

I added this in my webapiconfig.cs

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*") { SupportsCredentials = true };
```

and in my Web.Config I added

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<authorization>
  <allow users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

in my Fetch I just added

```
{
   method: "GET",
   headers: myHeaders,
   credentials: "include"
};
```

This works in IE11 and IE10!